# any way to return a the resultant random consonants or vowels that will be outputted as a string of length 8?

Tags: python

I am completely new to computer science and am not sure on how to collect the results and return them to the user as an 8 character string.

This is the code I made to give the user 8 random consonants or vowels based on what the user asks for.

```
count = 2
while count < 10:
char = input("v or c")
if char == "v":
    vow = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    v = random.choice(vow)
    print(v)
    count = count + 1

if char == "c":
    con = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 
't', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                 'y', 'z']
    c = random.choice(con)
    print(c)
    count = count + 1`
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Just collect the random choices in a list or a string:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'  # random.choice can choose from any type of sequence
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
chars = []  # collects the choices
for _ in range(8):  # for loop if iteration count is known beforehand
    select_char = input("Please enter either v for a vowel or c for a consonant: ")
    if select_char == "v":
        chars.append(random.choice(vowels))
    else:
        chars.append(random.choice(consonants))

print(''.join(chars))
```